# PyQT5: How to run an arbitrary Callable in a separate QThread, using the same worker definition?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

How can I define a worker so that I can run an arbitrary `Callable` in a separate QThread?

I tried using `lambda` expression to pass arguments at run-time, but this does not work (worker still runs in the main thread), see code below, method `run_in_separate_thread`:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from typing import Callable

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget, QPlainTextEdit,
)

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.resize(300, 150)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.text_edit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.bt = QPushButton("Run in separate thread", self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.bt)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.bt.clicked.connect(lambda: self.run_in_separate_thread(my_long_function))

    def report_progress(self, text: str) -> None:
        """ Report progress of function in separate thread """
        self.text_edit.appendPlainText(str(text))

    def run_in_separate_thread(self, function: Callable) -> None:
        """ Wrapper to run a function in a separate thread """

        self.thread = QThread(objectName="workerThread")
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.report_progress)

        self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.run(function))
        self.thread.start()


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self, function: Callable):
        function(self.progress)
        self.finished.emit()


def my_long_function(signal):
    print(f"mylongfunction thread: {QThread.currentThread().objectName(), int(QThread.currentThreadId())}")
    for _ in range(5):
        sleep(1)
        signal.emit("hello")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('main')
print(f"Main thread: {QThread.currentThread().objectName(), int(QThread.currentThreadId())}")
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This gives me the following output, and no "live" output is shown in the QTextEdit.

```
Main thread: ('main', 139754959259456)
mylongfunction thread: ('main', 139754959259456)
```

Is it because lambda expression "live" in the Main thread?
If I hard code `my_long_function` in the worker `run()` method and remove all lambdas expressions, it works as intended, see code below:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from typing import Callable

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget, QPlainTextEdit,
)

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.resize(300, 150)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.text_edit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.bt = QPushButton("Run in separate thread", self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.bt)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.bt.clicked.connect(self.run_in_separate_thread)

    def report_progress(self, text: str) -> None:
        """ Report progress of function in separate thread """
        self.text_edit.appendPlainText(str(text))

    def run_in_separate_thread(self) -> None:
        """ Wrapper to run a function in a separate thread """

        self.thread = QThread(objectName="workerThread")
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.report_progress)

        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.thread.start()


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        self.my_long_function()
        self.finished.emit()

    def my_long_function(self):
        print(f"mylongfunction thread: {QThread.currentThread().objectName(), int(QThread.currentThreadId())}")
        for _ in range(5):
            sleep(1)
            self.progress.emit("hello")


def my_long_function(signal):
    print(f"mylongfunction thread: {QThread.currentThread().objectName(), int(QThread.currentThreadId())}")
    for _ in range(5):
        sleep(1)
        signal.emit("hello")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('main')
print(f"Main thread: {QThread.currentThread().objectName(), int(QThread.currentThreadId())}")
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This gives following desired output:

```
Main thread: ('main', 139687209740096)
mylongfunction thread: ('workerThread', 139686815192832)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK here is a solution, by defining the Callable as an instance variable of the worker:

With this the worker is properly running in a separate thread.

full code:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from typing import Callable

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget, QPlainTextEdit,
)

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.resize(300, 150)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.text_edit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.bt = QPushButton("Run in separate thread", self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.bt)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.bt.clicked.connect(lambda: self.run_in_separate_thread(my_long_function))


    def report_progress(self, text: str) -> None:
        """ Report progress of function in separate thread """
        self.text_edit.appendPlainText(str(text))

    def run_in_separate_thread(self, f: Callable) -> None:
        """ Wrapper to run a function in a separate thread """

        self.thread = QThread(objectName="workerThread")
        self.worker = Worker()

        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.report_progress)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.worker.task = f
        self.thread.start()


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(str)
    task = None

    def run(self):
        self.task(self.progress)
        self.finished.emit()


def my_long_function(signal):
    print(f"mylongfunction thread: {QThread.currentThread().objectName(), int(QThread.currentThreadId())}")
    for _ in range(5):
        sleep(1)
        signal.emit("hello")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('main')
print(f"Main thread: {QThread.currentThread().objectName(), int(QThread.currentThreadId())}")
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```